# Convert pandas python data frame column values in place

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column of positive and negative numbers and I want to convert it to a list of 0s and 1s. If the number if positive, it should be replaced with a 1. If the number is negative or 0, it should be replaced by a 0. How can I do this?

For example, in R, I would do:

```
list = ifelse(list > 0, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return `boolean` values and use `astype(int)` to convert them to `1` and `0`.

```
print((df['A'] > 0).astype(int))
```

**Example:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,-1,2,-2,3,-3]})
print(df)
A
0  1
1 -1
2  2
3 -2
4  3
5 -3
print((df['A'] > 0).astype(int))
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    1
5    0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use an indexer and .loc to change values such has

```
 indexer = df[df['col']>0].index
 df.loc[indexer] = 1

  indexer_2 = df[df['col']<0].index
  df.loc[indexer_2] = 0
```

or you can look at numpy.where such has

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(np.where(df>0,1,0),index=df.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataFrame.apply` to apply a function to each row of your DataFrame. For instance:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, -2, 3, -4]})
df['A'] = df.apply(lambda row:np.where(row['A'] > 0, 1, 0), axis=1)
```

The `lambda` function can be replaced with any function (doesn't have to be a `lambda`), and `axis=1` is to apply the function to each row rather than each column.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html